# Build gdal with mrsid plugin on fedora 21 server

Tags: fedora, terminal, make, gdal

I've been having an issue for over a week now. The problem is, I can't build `gdal` source with `MrSid DSDK` on `Fedora 21 Server`. I have built and installed `gdal` with `MrSid` on `Fedora 21` without any problems and it works like a charm, but somehow it doesn't work on `Fedora 21 Server`.

I did exactly the same steps, as I did on `Fedora 21`. I have checked everything step by step and configured the source file as following:

```
--with-mrsid=/path/to/mrsidDSDK
```

After that, I ran `make` and it gave me the following errors:

```
make -C mrsid install-obj
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/frmts/mrsid'
/bin/sh /home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/libtool --mode=compile --tag=CXX g++ -g -O2 -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME  -Wall  -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/port -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/gcore -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/alg -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/ogr -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/ogr/ogrsf_frmts -DMRSID_J2K  -I../MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc44/Raster_DSDK/include -I../../frmts/gtiff/libgeotiff -DOGR_ENABLED -D_REENTRANT  -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/port  -c -o ../o/mrsiddataset.lo mrsiddataset.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -g -O2 -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -Wall -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/port -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/gcore -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/alg -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/ogr -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/ogr/ogrsf_frmts -DMRSID_J2K -I../MrSID_DSDK-9.1.0.4045-linux.x86-64.gcc44/Raster_DSDK/include -I../../frmts/gtiff/libgeotiff -DOGR_ENABLED -D_REENTRANT -I/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/port -c mrsiddataset.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o ../o/.libs/mrsiddataset.o
mrsiddataset.cpp:53:22: fatal error: lt_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lt_types.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
../../GDALmake.opt:562: recipe for target '../o/mrsiddataset.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [../o/mrsiddataset.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/frmts/mrsid'
GNUmakefile:10: recipe for target 'mrsid-install-obj' failed
make[1]: *** [mrsid-install-obj] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/ftp/diod/gdal-1.11.2/frmts'
GNUmakefile:63: recipe for target 'frmts-target' failed
make: *** [frmts-target] Error 2
```

So if there is anyone who has experienced the same problems, please help me?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the premise of your question. Fedora 21 Server _is_ Fedora 21, and has the same packages as Fedora 21 Workstation, Fedora 21 Cloud, or any of the other derivatives. The only difference, at this point, is in the default configurations and what's there out-of-box.

Comment: Maybe there are some packages that i must install first. On fedora 21 I installed gcc, gcc-c++, tbb in order to run make with mrsid configuration, and after that I had to build java bindings, so i installed swig, java-openjdk, and ant and it worked well. But on this fedora 21 server i did exact same steps still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling C programs on any edition of Fedora, you'll have best luck if you install the entire *C Development Tools and Libraries* group, rather than guessing piecemeal which parts might be required. Oh, and just plain *Development Tools* as well.

Different "flavors" of Fedora — from the desktop-focused Fedora Workstation to the, well, server-focused Fedora Server or cloud-focused Fedora Cloud — will have different software installed by default, so if you just pick a few requirements that you know exist and install those on whichever base, you might end up with more or less of what you actually need installed.

So, I'm *guessing* that if you do this:

```
sudo yum groupinstall development-tools c-development
```

you'll be all set.

(You can also use the longer names as well, in quotes to keep the spaces together. See the list of all groups with both long and short names with `yum -v grouplist`)

***However***, this does not actually explain your particular error. With the above advice, based on your note that it worked on non-server Fedora 21, I'm *guessing* that the error you give is a red herring, and that the actual problem happened somewhere earlier where preprocessor or other step failed. If installing the groups above does not fix the problem, double or triple check that you followed all the correct steps for your particular program.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have solved the problem. The problem was a simple mistake of mine. When i run `./configure` command i had to add the absolute path to the DSDK folder instead i was using the relative path like this `../path/to/dsdk` .